# Get result of function in Laravel and add to another controller

Tags: laravel-7

I have this 1st controller.

```php
class ValidatePassController extends Controller
{
    protected function doShow(Post $post, Hash $hash)
    {
        return view('auth.cab.pcab');
    }
}
```

I need to add `if view was returned` or something like that in the controller below.

```php
class EditController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function xuibomja()
    {
        if (// in past controller view was returned))
        {
            return ('stassik');
        }

        return ('not stassik');
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I have tried to set some `var`s, but it didn't work, so im out of ideas. Btw can't summary controllers to each other, codes needs to be in different controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the best practice to have a controller to call another controller.
what I recommend you to do is to create a class and move the functionality there, and create a facade to map to this class, and set both controllers to use that common functionality